# Which is better: <script type="text/javascript">...</script> or <script>...</script>

Tags: javascript, html

Which is better or more convenient to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
```

or

```
<script>...</script>
```

Comment: If you are using javascript as language then of course 1st one is better

Comment: I'm guessing the performance gain you get from declaring the script as java-script is insignificant, but great question!

Comment: Does the "correct" answer differ if it we are in Html v4 and Html v5?

Comment: It's not about which one is better but when to use what; when using HTML5 declaration `<!doctype html>`, there’s no need using the MIME type hint `type="text/javascript"` on a `<script>` tag as it applies by default. On the other hand (non-HTML5), it's advisable and recommended (with reference to the MIME type hint `type="text/javascript"`).

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Do you need a type attribute at all? If you're using HTML5, no. Otherwise, yes. HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1.0 specifies the `type` attribute as required while HTML5 has it as optional, defaulting to `text/javascript`. HTML5 is now widely implemented, so if you use the HTML5 doctype, `<script>...</script>` is valid and a good choice.

As to what should go in the type attribute, the MIME type `application/javascript` registered in 2006 is intended to replace `text/javascript` and is supported by current versions of all the major browsers (including Internet Explorer 9). A quote from [the relevant RFC](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt):

> This document thus defines text/javascript and text/ecmascript but marks them as "obsolete".  Use of experimental and unregistered media types, as listed in part above, is discouraged.  The media types,
>
> ```
>   * application/javascript
>   * application/ecmascript
> ```
>
> which are also defined in this document, are intended for common use and should be used instead.

However, IE up to and including version 8 doesn't execute script inside a `<script>` element with a `type` attribute of either `application/javascript` or `application/ecmascript`, so if you need to support old IE, you're stuck with `text/javascript`.

Comment: You don't "need" the `type` attribute. Validating against HTML4.01 or XHTML 1.0 is not what you should be doing anymore anyways, and all browsers will support your tag without `text/javascript`

Comment: @Ian: At the time of writing, the HTML5 spec was a working draft and had not yet morphed into its current status of perpetually moving target. Browser implementations of HTML5 were a considerable way behind where they are now. Considering this, I think HTML5 at the time was not viable for use on the general web and my answer was absolutely fair, and always carried the disclaimer *"if you want your HTML to be valid"*. I would agree that things have since moved on and this answer could do with revision, but I disagree that writing web pages in HTML 4.01 is now always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: +1, just discovered this question from a dupe.  It reminds me of [several posts](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1SVEA_enGB358GB358&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=anne+van+kesteren+script+type) on Anne Van Kesteren's blog, including [JavaScript MIME type](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/02/javascript-mime-type), where he discusses this.  I can't quite find it, but I was sure there was a post where he recommended to not use `type` at all because it works in all browsers.  Maybe it was someone else.

Comment: Just wanted to say "thanks" as I was trying to figure out why an "application/javascript" JS file was not being executed on IE8 and below!

Comment: what about: "text/javascript;version=1.8" ?

Comment: @SparK - `"text/javascript;version=1.8"` is for Firefox. According to this page about the [<script> tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type): "Note that in Firefox you can use advanced features such as let statements and other features in later JS versions, by using `"type=application/javascript;version=1.8"`. Beware, however, that as this is a non-standard feature, this will most likely break support for other browsers, in particular Chromium-based browsers."

Answer (score 10):

Both will work but xhtml standard requires you to specify the `type` too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">..</script> 

<!ELEMENT SCRIPT - - %Script;          -- script statements -->
<!ATTLIST SCRIPT
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED  -- char encoding of linked resource --
  type        %ContentType;  #REQUIRED -- content type of script language --
  src         %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- URI for an external script --
  defer       (defer)        #IMPLIED  -- UA may defer execution of script --
  >
```

---

> type = content-type [CI]
> This attribute specifies the scripting language of the element's
> contents and overrides the default
> scripting language. The scripting
> language is specified as a content
> type (e.g., "text/javascript").
> **Authors must supply a value for this
> attribute. There is no default value
> for this attribute.**

Notices the emphasis above.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html

**Note:** As of HTML5, the `type` attribute is not required and is default.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `<script type="text/javascript"> </script>` unless you're using html5. In that case you are encouraged to prefer `<script> ...  </script>` (because type attribute is specified by default to that value)

Answer (score 6):

This is all that is needed:

```
<!doctype html>
<script src="/path.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<script type="text/javascript"></script>` because its the right way and compatible with all browsers

Comment: That was the right way before HTML 5. HTML 5 was released two years before you wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML5, `<syntax>...</syntax>` is better and more convenient to use. If you are using HTML5, there is no need to mention `type = "text/javascript"` explicitly as **type** attribute is set to `"text/javascript"` by default, so it is completely optional.

Answer (score -5):

With the latest Firefox, I must use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
```

Or else the script may not run properly.

Comment: That isn't true