# Difference between script tag with & without type

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is better : <script type=“text/javascript”>..</script> or <script> … </script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243577/which-is-better-script-type-text-javascript-script-or-script-sc)

Can somebody tell me the difference between this two:

```
<script src="xyz.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script src="xyz.js">
</script>
```

Has it got anything related to cache? I mean, if the type is not included, will the file be downloaded and cached but not executed until another reference to this same file with type tag is set?

Comment: @BoltClock I mean in terms of caching.