# Why should all use <script type=javascript> instead <script>

Tags: javascript

I have seen many of developers are using

```
 <script type=javascript>
    //some code
 </script>
```

instead

```
<script>
    //some code
</script>
```

Why is main reason behind it? while basically this both are giving same result

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243577/which-is-better-script-type-text-javascript-script-or-script-scr

Comment: You need to use <script type="text/javascript"> </script> unless you're using html5. In that case you are encouraged to prefer <script> ... </script> (because type attribute is specified by default to that value)