# reCAPTCHA Image and Verification in the same index

Tags: javascript, php, forms, alert, recaptcha

I tried to make reCaptcha work in the same index. I tried this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
      <?php
        require_once('recaptchalib.php');
        $privatekey = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE";
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
          $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

          if (!$resp->is_valid) {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>
              window.alert('Sorry cannot send email as you have failed to provide correct captcha! Try again...')
            </script>";
          } else {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>
              window.alert('Thank you for submitting the track. We will be in touch with you very soon. Click Ok to redirect you to the Homepage.')
            window.location.href='http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/'
           </script>";
          }
       }
       $publickey = "YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE";
       echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
      ?>
     <br/>
     <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**The problem**

The `window.alert` and `window.location.href` are not working even if the answer is right or wrong.

When you click the Submit button it should popup an window.alert if the answer is good and redirect to homepage or popup a `window.alert` to retry if the answer is wrong.

Edit: You can run it. You need recaptchalib.php from google (link: https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:phplib-Latest)

Comment: Since none of us can run this code, you'll have to provide much more detail about the alert and the window.location *not working*.  Is there an error in the browser's console?   As a side note, `<script type="text/javascript">` is preferred: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243577/which-is-better-script-type-text-javascript-script-or-script-scr

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher You can run it. You need recaptchalib.php from google (link: https://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:phplib-Latest). I uploaded this already: http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/submit/index2.php When you click the submit button and the captcha is wrong, it should popup the window.alert('Sory cannot send bla bla') and if is good, it should popup the window.alert('Thank you for submitting bla bla') then redirect to my homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
<div class="php">
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY_HERE";
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
$resp = null;
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
window.alert('Sorry cannot send email as you have failed to provide correct captcha! Try again...')
window.location.href='http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/submit'
</script>";
} else {
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
$email_to = "sumutiumarius@gmail.com";
$email_subject = "Xmaster - Track Submission";
function died($error) {
echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
echo $error."<br /><br />";
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
die();
}
if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
!isset($_POST['artistname']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['track']) ||
!isset($_POST['links']) ||
!isset($_POST['type'])  ||
!isset($_POST['download'])  ||
!isset($_POST['free'])) {
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$artistname = $_POST['artistname'];
$emaila = $_POST['email'];
$track = $_POST['track'];
$links = $_POST['links'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$download = $_POST['download'];
$free = $_POST['free'];
$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$emaila)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($artistname) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Artist Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($track) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Track Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($links) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Links you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($type) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Type you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($download) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Download Link you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($free) < 1) {
$error_message .= 'The answer you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Submission form details below:\n\n";
    function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}
$email_message .= "Your Name: \n".clean_string($name)."\n\n";
$email_message .= "Artist Name: \n".clean_string($artistname)."\n\n";
$email_message .= "Your Email: \n".clean_string($emaila)."\n\n";
$email_message .= "Track Name: \n".clean_string($track)."\n\n";
$email_message .= "Your Links: \n".clean_string($links)."\n\n";
$email_message .= "Track Type: \n".clean_string($type)."\n\n";
$email_message .= "Download: \n".clean_string($download)."\n\n";
$email_message .= "Download Free: \n".clean_string($free)."\n\n";
$headers = 'From: '.$emaila."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$emaila."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
window.alert('Thank you for submitting the track. We will be in touch with you very soon. Click Ok to redirect you to the Homepage.')
window.location.href='http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/'
</script>";
}
}
}
?>
</div>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<table id="tabel" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<img src="http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/Images/name.png">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="name" class="rounded" maxlength="25">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<img src="http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/Images/artist.png">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="artistname" class="rounded" maxlength="25">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<img src="http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/Images/email.png">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="email" class="rounded" maxlength="40">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<img src="http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/Images/track.png">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="track" class="rounded" maxlength="60">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<img src="http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/Images/links.png">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<textarea name="links" class="rounded" maxlength="500" cols="28" rows="2"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<img src="http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/Images/type.png">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="type" class="rounded" maxlength="20">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<img src="http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/Images/downloadlink.png">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="download" class="rounded" maxlength="150">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<img src="http://www.xmasterofficial.tk/Images/downloadfree.png">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="free" class="rounded" maxlength="3">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input id="left" type="submit" class="submit" value=" ">
<input id="right" type="reset" value=" ">
<div id="captcha">
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "YOUR_PUBLIC_KEY_HERE";
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey, $error);
?>
</div>
</form>
```

P.S. This is a complete form with working captcha. You can use it as you wish. Don't forget to replace `$privatekey` and `$publickey` with your own keys. You can get keys from here: [Google reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha)