# When I link to jquery file, must I also put type="text/javascript"

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to get jquery to work in my text editor, but am not sure if I am linking correctly to the html file. Do I have to put `type="text/javascript"`  as well?
Here is the code. My css and jquery are in seperate files than my html page:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <link rel="./jquery' src='./animatetext.js"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
     <title>Animated text animation</title> 
    
  </head>
  <body>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243577/which-is-better-script-type-text-javascript-script-or-script-scr)?

Comment: you need use <script> when using  eksternal .js instead of <link>

Comment: The duplicates have very full and complete answers, but in short: no - so long as you're using HTML5, which you should be.

Answer (score -1):

```html
   
you can add jQuery to your html file by doing either of the below:

 1. downloading jQuery from [jQuery][1] then add a reference in the <head> section e.g 
     <head>
        <script src="~/{somePath}/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
     </head>

 2. through jQuery CDN e.g
      <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">. 
    </script>
    </head>

so you can confirm the downloaded jquery library path/location
```

Comment: This is not what the question is asking.

Comment: Thanks Hassain. I have changed it now, but my page still isn't showing anything. Would you know what else could be the problem. My text editor is notepad++. Here is the changed code: 
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
 
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="jquery-2.0.3.js" src=' ./animatetext.js"/></script>
 
  

  <title>Animated text animation</title>
 
 
  </head>

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve with jQuery? 
you can share the part where you're using jquery and not just the reference.
 @SpencerHalstead

Comment: The add comment section here will not let me put the code in, as it is too many characters. I am trying to do an animated text. Its not my code, I got it from a site that gives you snippets for animations using jquery. I am new at jquery, so I am just experimenting, seeing what this snippet will look like and if I can get jquery to work in notepad++.   When I put javascript snippets in, it usually works.